# Is my hiragana handwriting readable?

Tags: hiragana, handwriting

Even though I am in Japan for more than 4 months right now, I'm still worried about my Hiragana handwriting. Is it readable for Japanese? Because I know people had difficulties with reading my こ. Is there anything that has to change? (Well, I know it doesn't look like the beautiful characters in the chart when you first learn Hiragana.)

[image]

Comment: Don't worry too much. Although it might not be exactly text book hiragana, most Japanese people don't write very clearly, either. Compared to some handwritings I saw in highschool (even those of teachers), this looks totally fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ぜんぶ読めますよ。
自信を持ってください。
"こ"も読めます。

Answer (score 5):

Very good, but some hiraganas could be better.
Of course こ is very good.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's not very easily readable...

I had some problem figuring out the "ら" and especially the whole sentence next to your chart.

Comment: Maybe you should disclose that you are a beginner in Japanese. I'm not a native speaker either, but to me all of the characters are easily readable and I expect that native speakers will likewise not have any trouble reading OP's handwriting. (That said, the balance of some characters could be improved—mackygoo's answer addresses those.)

Comment: Well, I know my handwriting is not perfect. But a beginner might be wrong. Except you percieve a learner of Japanese for 4 years as beginner. But I'm glad it's readable.